# Codeigniter redirect doesn't update browser url

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect but it doesn't seems to work. The browser url does not update however i can see the view in (Network) inspect element.

**View Code**

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="<?= site_url(); ?>entrytest/printslips">
              <label>Filter Options</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="option">
                  <option value="all">Print All</option>
                  <option value="sort">Print Selected</option>
              </select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Print</button>
          </div>
            </form>
```

**Controller Code**

```
   public function printslips() { 
 //print_r($_POST);
    $option = $this->input->post('option');
    //echo $option;
    if($option == "all"){
      redirect( site_url() . 'student/print' );  
    }
    elseif($option == "sort"){
       echo $option;
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

> I can see the view loaded in networks but not in browser

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to return the redirect like this:

```
return redirect('your_controller');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public function printslips() { 
    $option = $this->input->post('option');
    if($option == "all"){
      redirect('student/print' );  
    }
    elseif($option == "sort"){
       echo $option;
    }
}
```

While redirectin controller action you dont need to pass site_url. Just pass controller and action name.

Or better to user AddMyTodo to redirect or calling function for your security purpose.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

`redirect('student/print' );`

No need for site url.  In redirect have to give controller name.